# UILabel truncates text regardless of multiline option

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UILabel` with line spacing to zero. When i'm displaying text it has 3 dot at the end. I don't understand why it's happening, `UILabel` height depends on text when line spacing is zero, so it doesn't need dots at the end. I need to somehow remove dots and show text completly.

Problem is in custom label class

```
class CustomLabel: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable
    var topInset: CGFloat = 0.0
    @IBInspectable
    var bottomInset: CGFloat = 0.0
    @IBInspectable
    var leftInset: CGFloat = 0.0
    @IBInspectable
    var rightInset: CGFloat = 0.0

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        let size = super.intrinsicContentSize
        return CGSize(width: size.width + leftInset + rightInset, height: size.height + topInset + bottomInset)
    }

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        let insets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
        super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: insets))
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the label to wrap in addition of setting .lines = 0 , you have to set a width constraint **OR** leading & trailing constraints or to it's container

Comment: distribution is `fill` ??

Comment: do you set width / lead & trailing to the stackview ?

Comment: I found problem... my label extends from UILabel. In my custom label i have opportunity to specify paddings. 

Please check updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is in a stackview, embed the UILabel in a UIView and set constraints label to view constraints.

```
UIStackView
  -> UIView
     -> UILabel
```

Answer (score 0):

correct way to do this, but in objective-C is like so. feel free to downvote, i don't care, and i won't translate to Swift, but you need to implement all three methods.

```
@implementation CustomLabel
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    _edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
  }
  return self;
}

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds limitedToNumberOfLines:(NSInteger)numberOfLines {
  return [super textRectForBounds:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds,self.edgeInsets) limitedToNumberOfLines:numberOfLines];
}

- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
  [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, self.edgeInsets)];
}

- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
  CGSize size = [super intrinsicContentSize];
  size.width  += self.edgeInsets.left + self.edgeInsets.right;
  size.height += self.edgeInsets.top + self.edgeInsets.bottom;
  return size;
}

@end
```